# How to block network trafic form outside network using iptable?

Tags: security, networking, ubuntu, iptables

My network system ip is in range 192.168.211.0/24. I have a web server on 192.168.211.50. I want to receive packets only from 192.168.211.0/24 range to my web server. How can i configure this using iptable in Ubuntu?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
iptables -I INPUT 1 -s 192.168.211.0/24 -j ACCEPT
iptables -I INPUT 2 -m state --state ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT
iptables -I INPUT 3 -j DROP
```